# It's possible to get the exit page in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Getting the referer page is possible in javascript with document.referer.

But is it possible to get the exit page in javascript ?

For example, my website is example.com. A visitor visits the page exemple.com, then he types in the url bar "www.aaaaaaa.com" to leave my website : i want to detect this url wwww.aaaaaaa.com by javascript.

Thank you in advance, cordially.

Comment: What do you mean by `exit page`?

Comment: Hello, I give more information in my question. For example, if a visitor visits your website then leave your website by typing a other website url in the url bar, the javascript must detect this exit url.

Comment: You can't. If the visitor is not on your website anymore (exemple.com), you can't see what he/she is doing.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert(window.location.href);
};` you can try this. however, not sure it it will work in every condition

Comment: Thank Tushar, but window.location.href detects the page from which the visitor leaves the website, not the new url. Imagine your visitor visits your website example.com, the leave your website by typing "foo.com" in the url bar : i want javascript detects this foo.com

Comment: What is your reason for wanting this?

Comment: To track the exit page for my web statistic.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `onbeforeunload` event. It is fired just before the page is unloaded.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
var exitPage =window.location.href ;
}
```

Save Exit Page in your cookie and to detect an address bar is changed you can check the current address periodically using setTimeout/interval:

```
var oldLocation = window.location.hostname;
setInterval(function() {
  if(window.location.hostname != oldLocation) {
       //do your action
      // oldLocation = location.href
  }
}, 1000); // check every second
```

But in this case you need to check domain name, because some times URL comes with different parameter.

Comment: Yes, but in the body of your function, how to detect the exit url ?

Comment: `window.location.href `

Comment: Thank you, but window.location.href detect the page from which the visitor leaves the website, not the new url. Imagine your visitor visits your website example.com, then leave your website by typing "foo.com" in the url bar : i want javascript detects this foo.com

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change) for more information.

Comment: Thank for the link, but hash is useless.

Comment: Thank, but in your updated answer, window.location.hostname detects only the hostname of your own website, not of a new website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83858/discussion-between-musakkhir-sayyed-and-totoaussi).

Comment: Musakkhir Sayyed thank you for your solution, it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to track the exit page for your web statistics you will just link to another forwarding page on your server and track the usage of that page. That's how it's generally done.

Alternatively, if you might consider using Google Analytics check this code:

```
<script>
/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Google Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that
* URL string as the event label.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
     function () {
     document.location = url;
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"
   onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">
Check out example.com
</a>
```

The code above was copied from this [page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920) and from here:  [Google Analytics Outbound Link Event Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711977/google-analytics-outbound-link-event-tracking)