# Outbound Link Tracking with Google Analytics with Django not working in production

Tags: django, google-analytics

I am attempting to track outbound link clicks with Google Analytics (GA).  Basic page logging works with GA.  In my development environment, outbound link tracking works.

Here is the script I have in my base page:

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

Here is an example anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Example Site</a>
```

I am running the site on a Digital Ocean app using nginx and gunicorn.

When a link is clicked, the status bar on the banner shows traffic to GA and then the browser is redirected to the original page with the link url appended to it.

```
https://original-site.com/slug_of_page/www.example.com
```

This generates a 404

This is not a duplicate question as the question cited is the code I am using almost verbatim.

Comment: How it is linked with `Django`?

Comment: The website involved is running Django in gunicron with an nginx server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics Outbound Link Event Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711977/google-analytics-outbound-link-event-tracking)

Comment: The code in the "possible duplicate" is identical to mine, yet mine does not work.